# Why do Unity networking libraries fail when building for the Windows Store?

Tags: c#, unity, networking, windows-8

I am using [Lidgren](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/) and RSA in my networking framework, but things like IPAddress are "nonexistent" when I try building for windows store. RSA classes don't work, either.

Why is this? How could I still have a networked game on the Windows Store?

Answer (score 1):

The *Getting Started* page for building Unity apps for Winows store specifically says Unity [**doesn't support** networking on Windows Store platforms](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-gettingstarted.html).

It does mention that WWW functions work correctly though.  If you're desperate, try porting your networking to HTTP.

Comment: Note that this answer from 2015 isn't quite true anymore. Legacy Networking isn't supported, but Unity Networking is supported for Windows Store.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Nice! Could you post that as an answer?